# IOS5 __block variable throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS outside scope

Tags: ios, ios5, mapkit

I'm baffled as to why I cannot access my global variable again after it has been through a block. Here is my code:

```
__block NSString *latitude;
__block NSString *longitude;

CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:location completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) 
{
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
    {
        CLLocation *latLong = aPlacemark.location;
        latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.latitude];
        longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.longitude];
        //works fine
        NSLog(@"CLLOCATION SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS LAT: %@, LONG: %@", latitude, longitude);           
    }
}];

//no bueno
NSLog(@"CLLOCATION SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS LAT: %@, LONG: %@", latitude, longitude);
```

Now I've tried initializing my `NSString`s in different ways:

```
__block NSString *latitude = @"";
__block NSString *longitude = @"";
```

and:

```
__block NSMutableString *latitude = [NSMutableString string];
__block NSMutableString *longitude = [NSMutableString string];
```

But I just wind up getting empty strings when I am accessing the variables outside of the block.

This is particularly baffling because in Apple's documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

, they're able to set variables outside of blocks, use them, and retrieve them just fine.

Comment: Try not to use the `<code>` tags;  highlight the code and select the button that looks like `{}` on top of the text field.

Comment: Just tried. Made it look even worse. Sorry. This is one of the most confusing sites I've ever been on.

Comment: Did it indent your code by four spaces?

Comment: Stack Overflow uses markdown when writing questions, answers and comments. You can read about how to use it in the ["Markdown editing help"-page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If you don't wan't to use markdown there are buttons you can use to style your text as code, bold, italic etc. in the UI where you asked your question (they are right above the text field)

Comment: Looks good now. Did an admin change it or something?

Comment: @JohnBowlinger or something :)

Comment: Is your last placemark `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okie doke, sounds like a couple of issues (one, none or all may apply, it's hard to tell within the context you've provided):

1 - *"But I just wind up getting empty strings when I am accessing the variables outside of the block."*

Depends when you're accessing them outside the block. This is because there is no guarantee that latitude and longitude will have been populated at the time of querying them. The block provided is a completion handler for CLGeocoder; it will be called when the geocoder has found locations of interest. Being able to retrieve location data, and to do a search based on that location takes time, and the NSLog statement straight after has a high probability of being called before any 'placemarks' have been found.

2 - *"IOS5 __block variable throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS outside scope"*

You are assigning the following in the block:

```
latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.latitude];
longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.longitude];
```

`stringWithFormat` is a method that returns an autoreleased value, but you're not retaining them anywhere. If you're not using ARC (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html for ARC in memory management terms, and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html generally), then this will cause issues when accessing the values elsewhere, as you're accessing an object that no longer exists. If you are using ARC, then this shouldn't be a problem, as the variables will be strong by default, and retain the value for you.

Comment: latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.latitude]copy];
longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.longitude]copy];

Comment: latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.latitude]retain];
longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.longitude]retain];

Comment: Getters and setters. [self setLatitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.latitude]];
[self setLongitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latLong.coordinate.longitude]];

Comment: But I cannot get those things to stick!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what context you're using this in, can you update your question with a snippet of code which demonstrates this problem, and contains the variable's location and method(s) being used.

I should also note that if not using ARC, then `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"..."]` would be better if you want it retained. Can you confirm whether you're using ARC or not, as it'll influence the way this issue is sorted.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger - Did you read part 1 of his answer? The CLGeocoder completion handler is a block that is performed asynchronously from the rest of the code there (it states as much in the documentation for this method). Nothing will have been run or set by the time you get to the NSLog statements outside of the completion handling block, which is why it doesn't matter what you do with those values inside the block. They won't be set until that block is performed, which will happen at some point in the future, well after you try to log them outside of the block in the code you show above.

Comment: I don't know much about posting on this website so I'll just accept the answer. Thanks guys.